# Save a TiniFile from application to iOS

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

I am very new to the iOS platform. I am trying to save an INI file for my application. The problem is that I can't get a path with write permission.

Here is my code:

```
  ini := TIniFile.Create(GetHomePath + '/user.dat');
  try
    ini.WriteString('data','user',edtuser.Text);
    ini.WriteString('data','descr',edt1.Text);
  finally
    ini.Free;
  end;
```

I get an exception that the file can't be created. How can I get a writable path using Firemonkey?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` (and use `TPath.Combine` instead of concatenation, to remove the hard-coded `/`):

```
uses
  System.IOUtils;


ini := TIniFile.Create(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'user.dat'));
```

Using `TPath.GetDocumentsPath` works across all supported platforms (Win32, Win64, OSX, iOS, and Android) transparently, and using `TPath.Combine` will automatically add the `TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar`, so you don't have to manually concatenate them.

If you prefer to do it yourself, though:

```
var
  IniName: string;
begin
  IniName := TPath.GetDocumentsPath + TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar + 'user.dat';
  Ini := TIniFile.Create(IniName);
  try
    // Rest of code
  finally
    Ini.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

May be [this](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/stephenball/2013/07/24/ini-files-on-ios/) or [this](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29501) can help you

```
uses INIFiles;

function TForm6.MyINIFilePath: string;
begin
//  Result := GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'Library' + PathDelim+'My.ini';
  Result := GetHomePath + PathDelim + 'Documents' + PathDelim+'MyD.ini';
end;
```